# pipenv install packages failes

Tags: pip, pipenv

I'm trying to install packages from a `Pipfile` with `pipenv` but I keep getting an error I don't know how debug.

```
pip --version
pip 18.1

pipenv --version
version 2018.10.9
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
pipenv install --dev --deploy

Courtesy Notice: Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment, so it will automatically use that environment, instead of creating its own for any project. You can set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to ignore that environment and create its own instead. You can set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 to suppress this warning.
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (917af8)…
An error occurred while installing backports-ssl-match-hostname==3.5.0.1 --hash=sha256:502ad98707319f4a51fa2ca1c677bd659008d27ded9f6380c79e8932e38dcdf2! Will try again.
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 185/185 — 00:00:33
Installing initially failed dependencies…
Collecting backports-ssl-match-hostname==3.5.0.1 :00

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement backports-ssl-match-hostname==3.5.0.1 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-qlbc3amj-requirements/pipenv-akfm2pt_-requirement.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for backports-ssl-match-hostname==3.5.0.1 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-qlbc3amj-requirements/pipenv-akfm2pt_-requirement.txt (line 1))

  ☤  ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 0/1 — 00
```

Looking at the `Pipfile.lock` I can find the `backports` package defined as:

```
   "backports.ssl-match-hostname": {
        "hashes": [
            "sha256:502ad98707319f4a51fa2ca1c677bd659008d27ded9f6380c79e8932e38dcdf2"
        ],
        "version": "==3.5.0.1"
    },
```

Running everything with the verbose flag, the backports package is a dependency from `recurly` which is in the `Pipfile`:

```
 recurly = ">=2.8.6"
```

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade your pip version to 18.0.0 while your pipenv shell is active

```
python -m pip install pip==18.0.0
```

It worked for me